# Different moderators respond differently to the same type of flags

Tags: support, flags, declined-flags

I sometimes flag questions that should be moved to a different Stack Exchange site. For example I flagged

[How to define the WP_QUERY class in an external php file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9803604/how-to-define-the-wp-query-class-in-an-external-php-file)

with

> it belongs to wordpress.stackexchange.com I think

and it was flagged helpful. While

[Execute php function in another part of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9869933/execute-php-function-in-another-part-of-code)

with the same

> it belongs to wordpress.stackexchange.com I think

was flagged

> declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

so should I still flag questions that should be moved or not?

Comment: We're only human. There will be differences between moderators and even the same moderator might respond to the same flag differently at different times.

Comment: You don't even know if that was a different moderator. As you can see, neither question was migrated, so it could be the same moderator who's telling you to slow down with the migration flags. Migrations are supposed to be uncommon, and if I understand [wordpress.se]'s scope, not everything tagged [tag:wordpress] belongs there.

Comment: @ChrisF this is not to be polemic, i was just asking if i should do that or not, maybe i should change the question title

Comment: @lunboks the second time i was told that i shouldn't flag those question because they don't need moderator attention, if i shouldn't flag those, i won't flag them anymore, simple as that! :)

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti "flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention" is just one of the standard decline reasons, don't read too much into it.

Comment: @YannisRizos ah ok, didn't know that! :)

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti The other two are: "a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it" & "flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer". And there is also a custom decline message, if you ever get one of those it means that the moderator went through the trouble of writing a specific message to you. That may or may not be more important than the standard declines, depending on what the message actually says.

Comment: It should be noted that WP is *quite particular* about the type of questions they suggest.  We don't migrate many questions over there in general.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are three possible scenarios:

1. Both flags are invalid, in which case your first flag shouldn't have been marked as helpful,
2. The first flag is valid and the second one is not, in which case they were both handled correctly,
3. Both flags are valid, in which case your second flag shouldn't have been declined.

And there is another less obvious scenario, where both your flags are invalid but the moderator who reviewed your first flag though that it had at least *some* merit, so they decided to mark it as helpful.

None of the questions was migrated, which tells me that the moderator who marked your first flag as helpful didn't agree that the question should be moved to Wordpress Stack Exchange. So I'd say that scenarios (1) and (4) are the more likely ones.

In any case, why does it matter? It's even possible that both flags where handled by the same moderator. There should be consistency in moderation actions, of course, but at the end of the day we are only human. And a single flag is such a minor detail in a moderator's day, especially on the vast wilderness that is Stack Overflow.

Keep on flagging, if you feel your flags have merit, it's just a communication mechanism nothing more.

Comment: Mods have been pressur... er, instructed to decline less flags.  If the user was sorta right in the flag, we just mark it as helpful and move on.  Helpful != acted upon.